# Как организовать подпись пользователя в группе?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Мне нужно чтобы в моей телеграмм группе каждый пользователь имел индивидуальную подпись, который он сам установит.

То есть чтобы в каждое его сообщение в группу вначале вставлялась его подпись.

Не могу придумать как это организовать. Ведь насколько я знаю телеграм бот не может редактировать чужие сообщения.

Я сделал чтобы пользователь установил подпись через бота и сохранил ее в базу, назначил бота админом. Но вот вся загвоздка в том что нельзя боту редактировать чужое сообщение.

Только если цитировать каждое сообщение и отправлять подпись, но это очень плохое решение, так как на каждое сообщение от пользователя будет сообщение бота, что засорит чат.

Как можно организовать это более удобно?